# note: in expansion of macro 'A_MACRO'

Tags: c, gcc

I have hundred of warnings like this when build with `gcc`:

```
foo.c:2690:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘PUT_UINT32’
     PUT_UINT32(state, digest,  0);
```

How can I get rid of them?

`-w` also hide warnings that I still want to see

Comment: A side note: Hiding warnings is generally a bad way of dealing with them. They are there for a reason.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with `gcc`?  In OSX, `gcc` is a thin wrapper on `clang`.

Comment: Indeed it is wise to enable most warnings and fix the code. `-Wall -Werror` are your friends.

Comment: I think a better question to ask would be `What do they mean?`. But, if you just want to hide them, then you could simply `gcc [files] >> compile_log.txt 2>&1`, then open it in vim, `/note:`, `gg`, `qqnd2jq`, `:set nu`, `:g/note/m0`, read the line number of the last `note` line, `ugg`, `<number of lines>@q`. That will delete all occurrences of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are using `clang`: when `clang` detects an error or a warning in code expanded from a macro, it outputs one line for each macro whose expansion leads to the offending code.  Fix the errors and warnings in the final code and these messages will disappear.

Comment: Well, I just realized with your answer that this is much more than juste a `note`. There is a smelly thing behind and the good news is that I just found it

Comment: I am trying to extract and build the encryption part of vim sources in order to understand it. I wanted just to build these too files. It took some time because of the multiple dependancies. During the process I made one bug mistake. I replaced a `unsigned char` with a `unsigned char*`. I did not have much warning, no errors and hundred `note` about macro expansion. With the correction I got rid of this note message.

Comment: All these `note` lines should relate to actual warnings and/or error lines

Comment: Note: you get these notes as well when compiling with `gcc -pedantic`. I came here because I want to know what it's trying to tell me by pointing at a macro. Aside from notes, the only warnings I'm getting are `warning: non-ISO-standard escape sequence`. So, if I have this right, GCC is just trying to tell me that my code will print stuff like `"^[0;47;30m"` in e.g. a Windows terminal. Good thing I already tested for that. If the system isn't `__linux__`, then it defaults to the basic text-only renderer that doesn't use [ANSI escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).